# function fact_of_ k returns segmentation fault, when k is 0

Tags: c

I want to know why this program gives me a segmentation error. Kindly note that I've solved this problem by changing the value of variable k from 0 to 1. Though it solved my problem, I want to know what happens with the logic/system when k is 0?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fact_of_nk(int);
int fact_of_k(int);
int fact_of_n(int);

int main()
{
    int fact_n, fact_k, fact_nk, bmu, k = 0, nk;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 10; n++)
    {
        fact_n = fact_of_n(n);
    
        while (k <= n)
        {
            fact_k = fact_of_k(k);
            int nk = (n - k);
            printf("%d ", nk);
            k++;
        }
        k = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}


    int fact_of_n (int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return number * fact_of_n(number - 1);
}

    int fact_of_k (int choose)
{
    if (choose == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return choose * fact_of_k(choose -1);
}

    int fact_of_nk (int choose)
{
    if (choose == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return choose * fact_of_nk(choose - 1);
}
```

Comment: First of all format your code properly.

Comment: What are `fact_of_n` and `fact_of_k`? And what did you change exactly in your code? There are two `k = 0` in your code.

Comment: No seeing any issue with code wich you have shared. "fact_of_k(k);" result from this function is not used anywhere. can we comment this function and see whether crash is seen or not, otherwise issue is with "fact_of_k(k);" function call.

Comment: Functions `fact_of_k()` and `fact_of_n()` do nothing that affects anything in `main()`, and `main()` simply prints sequences of numbers. So if there if there is any fault, it is the functions you did not post.

Comment: sorry for the format of the code. I am new to coding and its related forums. I still tried to format it as per the requirement, yet I fail every time. About my problem: fact_of_k and fact_of_n are the custom functions to get the factorial. Should I post it? The reason I want to know its behaviour so that I can handle it in future.

Comment: I indented the code for you. -- Since the source you show us currently has no detectable problem, please [edit] your question and provide the source of the called functions.

Comment: Of course you should post the `fact_of_k` and `fact_of_n` functions. How else are we possibly supposed to find out what's wrong in your code?

Comment: I suspect that ```fact_of_k``` is recursive factorial function that doesn't handle the base case k=0, and thus goes into infinite recursion and overflows the stack.

Comment: Because of recursion. Maybe do k+1 not k-1?

Comment: @MKSundaram click the `?` icon on the top right of the editing pane and you'll see [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also take the [tour] and click the `?` icon at the top right of the page where a help section is available and you can also find out how to format there

Comment: Sure I will visit how to format section and try to understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a stack overflow here because the recursion never ends if you call `fact_of_k(0)`

```
int fact_of_k(int choose)
{
  printf("Choose = %d\n", choose);   // <<<< add this

  if (choose == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return choose * fact_of_k(choose - 1);
}
```

Check this modified function and see what the output is, you'll understand.

Hint for correction: modify slightly this line:

```
if (choose == 1)
```

Comment: Now I see the base case will never be true to stop the calling and hence the error. Now I am clear why the error. Thanks for explaining it in simple steps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code gets a segmentation fault because of recursion. Look at what happens in your program. You pass `k` to `fact_of_k`. `k` is 0, and `0 != 1`. So it calls `fact_of_k` again, this time with `0 - 1`, so -1. -1 is not one, so it calls `fact_of_k` again, this time passing -2. You can see the problem. Using recursion too much gets a segmentation fault, which is why your program doesn't work.